# c# File.WriteAllBytes raises "Access denied" exception, while "FileStream.Write" succeeds

Tags: c#, windows, ntfs

I have the following code:

```
var cnt = new byte[] { 0xaa, 0xbb };
var fileName = @"C:\ProgramData\path\to\myfile.bin";

try
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, cnt);
    Console.WriteLine(("WriteAllBytes OK"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WriteAllBytes Exception: " + ex.Message);
}

try
{
    using (var f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        f.Write(cnt, 0, 2);
        f.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("FileStream.Write OK");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("FileStream.Write Exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

this code gives the following output:

```
WriteAllBytes Exception: Access denied to path 'C:\ProgramData\path\to\myfile.bin'.
FileStream.Write OK
```

I added Everyone/Full control to file permissions and assigned file ownership to MYPC\MyUser.

I used Process Monitor to see what's going on, this is the output:

> CreateFile    C:\ProgramData\Path\to\myfile.bin   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: 0    MYPC\MyUser 00000000:0002d238

> CreateFile    C:\ProgramData\Path\to\myfile.bin   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened MYPC\MyUser 00000000:0002d238
> WriteFile C:\ProgramData\Path\to\myfile.bin   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 2, Priority: Normal  MYPC\MyUser 00000000:0002d238
> CloseFile C:\ProgramData\Path\to\myfile.bin   SUCCESS     MYPC\MyUser 00000000:0002d238

I don't understand why in this situation WriteToFile fails.

Comment: Is there any specific permission set for this file ?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: `WriteAllBytes` uses `FileStream` in a similar way under the hood. The main difference is it demands `FileMode.Create` instead of `Open`. I would check the file (and folder) permissions very carefully. You could also change `FileMode` in your working code to see if that then fails.